# Passing variable of one file to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I want to pass a variable of one javascript file to second file by calling function defined in second file. I have already used object, string and have applied many more methods but nothing is helping me. Here is the sample code..

```
    <script src="setup.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>feed="codplex" ; someVar.add(feed) ; </script>
```

The function defined in setup.js to update the value of its local variable according to the passed variable is..

```
var someVar = (function () {
  var link = "https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=" ;
return{
    add: function(feed){
      link += feed;
    }
} ;
}());
```

but its not working..The value of `link` variable is not updating. Can anyone please help me..

Comment: how did you know the value of `link` is not updating? it's just a local variable defined in a self-executed function, the returned object (saved into `someVar`) exposes only one method `add`.

Comment: Based on comments to my answer, it's safe to say that the actual code being asked about is quite different from the code in the question. Can you update your question with an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You don't know it doesn't work (or does), because `someVar` doesn't expose the value of `link` at all.

If you return one more function that does expose it, for example

```
var someVar = (function () {
  var link = "https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=" ;
  return {
    add: function(feed){
      link += feed;
    }, 
    getLink: function() { 
      return link; 
    }
  };
}());
```

`someVar.getLink()` will be what you expect.

Comment: i actually have one more function to open the link but it is opening previous value of link. How can i permanently change the value of link so that its value does not get effected when other function opens it.

Comment: If that's the case, then your actual code is different from your question code in an important way - in your question's code, it is impossible for `link` to be accessed outside of the IIFE that creates `someVar`